# Should we modify a function signature for unit testing?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing

Suppose we have a function `add()` as below:

```
void add(int a, int b) {
    int sum=a+b;
    cout<<sum;
    sendSumToStorage(sum);
}
```

This simple function adds to input values, prints the sum to the console and also sends it to some external storage (say, a file).  This is how we ideally want it in the application (meaning, we don't want it to *return anything*).

For purposes of unit testing, is it valid (from a design perspective) if we modify the function signature so that it returns the `sum`?  We could then have a test like:

```
bool checkAdd() {
    int res=add(3, 4);
    if(res==7) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Better yet, is this (*returning a value*) the only way we could unit test it?  Is there some *valid* way in which we could unit test the `add()` function without changing the function signature?

Comment: It'd be more normal to somehow observe the value sent to the storage maybe by using a mock class

Comment: @AlanBirtles, could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you add a [mre] then I could

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function like the one in your example is considered really bad practice.

Why do I say this?

Well, you have a method called **add** which adds two numbers **AND** calls something else. Basically your method doesn't do one thing, but two, which violates the Single Responsibility Principle.

This makes things much harder to test because you can't test just the add method in isolation.

So you would separate that into two methods with good names which reflect what they do and test them separately.

If you don't want to have issues with state between your methods, you will have to start returning results where it makes sense.

Comment: I vehemently agree with what you say; but please note that the above is _just_  an example.  It might be more helpful to think that the function has only two tasks (like that of a transporter) - to send to the console and also to storage.  The calculations being carried out here are just some config parameters related to how to send over the data.  And it is these config parameters that we want to test.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that this example has a bad desing.

For cases like this, when you want to check some internal behaviour instead of API you should rather try using some testing libraries like gtest and gmock.
It allows you to describe more sophisticated expectations than just function result.

For example you can set expectation that some method will be called during code execution using EXPECT_CALL macro.

More details here:
https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md

Answering your question, it's always a bad practice to modify any part of tested code for the purpose of testing. In that case you are not longer testing production code. As it was suggested before it's better to split the functionality into smaller parts and test them isolated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the design of code to improve testability is very common and generally considered as a good practice.  Obviously, not all such changes are necessarily real improvements - sometimes better solutions exist.

In your case, the code is difficult to test because it combines computations (the addition) with interactions with depended-on components (output and storing data).  In your case (as Andrei has pointed out) the function also violates the SRP, but mixing computations and interactions generally makes testing more difficult, even in cases where the SRP is not violated.

I understand, you would change the function such that it will return the computed value in addition to printing it and writing it to the storage.  This will allow you to test the computational part of the function.  The function will then, however, only be partially tested.  And, the purpose of the function will be further obfuscated.

If instead you split the function into one function doing the computation and one doing the interactions, you can thoroughly test the first with unit-testing, and use integration-testing for the other.  Again, the usefulness of this approach is independent of whether the code violates the SRP or not.